# Iterating drawing sprites onto the game board via grid // size of prefab/sprite in pixels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I need to iterate the players on the game board so be automated in size across platform. Something like a chess board.

I need 10 sprites across the x-axis with each grid element as the width of the initial sprite.

I'm wondering if I can get the size of the sprite in pixels to divide by Screen.width (Game width in pixels).

Sorry if it's not very clear I'm not very good in explaining this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? please post your code with issues(if any).

Comment: I'm an idiot. 

Can just use Camera.main.orthapegicSize and scale.